# Animation for Continuous Movement in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to have a box or image object be able to translate around the screen using X and Y coordinates received from the console/command-line or external app. Is there a way to tweak the Modifier PointerInput() to accept continuous X and Y inputs instead of detecting drag gestures? I am using Jetpack Compose API.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val animationState = remember{ mutableStateOf(false)}

        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
        val imageSize = 200.dp



// Receive X,Y inputs from some device or continously read from command line inputs
        do{
            offsetX = 0.dp
            offsetY = 5000.dp
        } while(animationState.value)


        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = Color.White)
        ) {
            someImage(
                flashyMovement = animationState.value,
                maxWidth = maxWidth,
                maxHeight = maxHeight,
                offsetX = offsetX,
                offsetY = offsetY
            )

        }
    }

@Composable
fun someImage(
maxWidth: Dp,
maxHeight: Dp,
offsetX: Dp,
offsetY: Dp) {

val resource: Painter
val modifier: Modifier
val imageSize = 200.dp

    val xPositionState = infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 20000,
                easing = LinearEasing
            )
        )
    )

    modifier = Modifier.offset(
        x = offsetX,
        y = offsetY
    )

}
Image(
    modifier = modifier.width(imageSize).height(imageSize),
    painter = resource,
    contentDescription = "some Image",
)}


            Box() {
            var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

            Box(
                Modifier
                    .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .size(150.dp)
                    //.border(BorderStroke(2.dp, SolidColor(Color.Red)))
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consumeAllChanges()
                            //offsetX += dragAmount.x
                            offsetX = 150.dp.toFloat() 
                            offsetY += dragAmount.y
                        }
                    }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var OffsetX = remember { Animatable(0f) }
var OffsetY = //same as abov
```

Inside `Modifier.offset { IntOffset(OffsetX.value, OffsetY.value) }`.pointerInput(Unit)

````
coroutineScope.launch{
while(true)
pointerID = awaitPointerEvent{ awaitFirstDown().id }
drag(pointerID){change ->
offsetX.snapTo(offsetX.value + change.positionChange().x)
//Similarly for Y
}
}
}
}```
````

Comment: There is no function called snapTo and drag

Comment: Also the problem with this awaitPointerEvent() method is that it requires one to tap once on some random part of the screen clear of any other UI elements in order to activate the any animation to the box. I think I might need to run this somehow on a background service.